# Self-adjoint operators and positive

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be two self-adjoint operators in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}$ with $\dim \mathbb{E} < \infty$ with inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$. The quadratic form $Q(x) = (\varphi(x), x)$ is positive difinite. Prove that the characteristic polynomial of $\varphi\psi$ can be decomposed into linear factors.

The thing that I have found out is that $Q(x) = \lambda_1 (e_1,e_1) + \ldots + \lambda_n(e_n, e_n)$ in some eigenbasis of $\varphi$ where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues. Since $Q$ is positive definite, all $\lambda_i > 0$. Can you give me a hint what to do next? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\varphi \psi$ is similar to $\varphi^{1/2}\psi\varphi^{1/2}=\varphi^{-1/2}(\varphi \psi)\varphi^{1/2}$.

Comment: I see how it can help but I don't understand why it is correct. Can you explain?

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Yeah. Now I see what you mean, Thank you very much! :)